# XSL file to add one new tag to soap xml

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xslt, soap

I am new to XSLT stuff. 
Basically, I need to update incoming soap xml by adding one line with some namespaces in between. Can you please suggest an XSL doing this for me? 
One other question, where exactly should I place the XSL file to take action for all incoming requests?

```
Incoming Requests:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <consultaRegistros>
         <id>231</id>
         <numero>1231</numero>
         <registros_alta>
            ......
         </registros_alta>
      </consultaRegistros>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>


To be transformed to:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:les="LEServico">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
        <les:consultaRegistrosReq>
          <consultaRegistros>
             <id>231</id>
             <numero>1231</numero>
             <registros>
                ......
             </registros>
          </consultaRegistros>
        </les:consultaRegistrosReq>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform this:

```
  <consultaRegistros>
     <id>231</id>
     <numero>1231</numero>
     <registros_alta>
        ......
     </registros_alta>
  </consultaRegistros>
```

to this:

```
    <les:consultaRegistrosReq xmlns:les="LEServico">
      <consultaRegistros>
         <id>231</id>
         <numero>1231</numero>
         <registros>
            ......
         </registros>
      </consultaRegistros>
    </les:consultaRegistrosReq>
```

using the template rules:

```
<xsl:template match="consultaRegostros">
  <les:consultaRegistrosReq xmlns:les="LEServico">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </les:consultaRegistrosReq>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="registros_alta">
  <registros>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </registros>
</xsl:template>
```

Plus the standard identity rule to copy other elements unchanged.

Note this won't put the namespace declaration on the outermost element as in your example, but the result will be equivalent.

I con't advise you on how to set up your configuration to apply this transformation because I don't know enough about your processing environment.

Comment: Thank you for the details. 
My application is a simple webservice application built in java and deployed on weblogic. My question is should I be adding this XSLT file somewhere in my java applicaiton or it should stay somewere on server where my application runs?

Comment: Maintain it as a file on the server, and invoke the transformation from your Java application. Organize it so that you only compile the stylesheet once, not on each use.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please suggest an XSL doing this for me?

No, it's a rather unique need and there is no pre-existing XSLT example out there that will do it for you. You will need to learn basic XSLT and make one yourself.

> One other question, where exactly should I place the XSL file to take action for all incoming requests?

I strongly suggest skipping XSLT entirely and just alter the incoming SOAPMessage object to add the element you want to add.